# ESP8266 RTOS SDK pin 16 declaration not found

Tags: c, esp8266

I am working on a firmware project using [ESP-WROOM-02](http://espressif.com/en/products/hardware/esp-wroom-02/overview) and a modified custom board with an ESP-WROOM-02 on it. On the custom board, I have pin `IO16` connected to a hardware ON/OFF subcircuit and therefore I have to set pin `IO16` in `GPIO/OUTPUT` mode.

However, I cannot find a declaration for pin `IO16` in [ESP8266 RTOS SDKS's pin_mux_register.h](https://github.com/vowstar/esp8266-rtos-sdk/blob/master/include/espressif/esp8266/pin_mux_register.h) and I cannot set up this pin. Why is pin `IO16` excluded from the ESP8266 RTOS SDK? Here is a partial schematic with pin `IO16` labeled as FAN:

[image]

Comment: Someone has marked this off topic as being more suitable for SuperUser, but this is clearly a development question about an SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pin is badly commented in [ESP8266 RTOS SDK](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK) and other documentation, however, I've managed to set it up via:

```
void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR gpio16_output_conf(void)
{
    WRITE_PERI_REG(PAD_XPD_DCDC_CONF,
                   (READ_PERI_REG(PAD_XPD_DCDC_CONF) & 0xffffffbc) | (uint32)0x1);      // mux configuration for XPD_DCDC to output rtc_gpio0

    WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_GPIO_CONF,
                   (READ_PERI_REG(RTC_GPIO_CONF) & (uint32)0xfffffffe) | (uint32)0x0);      // mux configuration for out enable

    WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_GPIO_ENABLE,
                   (READ_PERI_REG(RTC_GPIO_ENABLE) & (uint32)0xfffffffe) | (uint32)0x1);    //out enable
}
```

taken from [IoT Demo GPIO16.c](https://github.com/willemwouters/ESP8266/blob/master/sdk/esp_iot_sdk_v0.9.3/IoT_Demo/driver/gpio16.c) implementation file.